# Flashing repair question

Tags: repair, leak, roof, roofing, flashing

Does anyone have any suggestions on correcting this roof flashing? Leaking occurs during storms and when water is directed under the flashing that extends on the shed roof.  The existing house roof intersects into this shed roof creating the valley (shown) but the flashing extends too far out and has its right side exposed such that water and leaves (plus other debris/insects) can get under it.[image: Flashing view 1][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzkRn.jpg)
[image: Flashing view 3]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzkRn.jpg): [image: flashing view 2]

Comment: Wouldn't another piece of L shaped flashing, tucked under the edge of the shingles on the main roof, so that the lip is parallel to the lip of the flashing from the shed roof, work?

Comment: That doesn't look right, although this , I feel is not the best suggestion, the lower roof shingle should extend under the upper roof where it looks like it was redone at one time. There is a section in the middle between the lower "W" flashing which is all wrong and the valley flashing by the pictures doesn't look right either by the way it is finished at the lower end where it meets the shed roof section